# Please explain why it "doesn't even make sense to change the value of a number"

Tags: javascript, computer-science

I'm just reading [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596805531.do) by David Flanagan.  I'm really enjoing and I'm happy my first Javascript book is this one. :)

However, I can't make much sense of this paragraph (3.7 Immutable Primitive Values and Mutable Object
References):

> There is a fundamental difference in JavaScript between primitive values (`undefined`,
>   `null`, booleans, numbers, and strings) and objects (including arrays and functions).
>   Primitives are immutable: there is no way to change (or “mutate”) a primitive value.
>   This is obvious for numbers and booleans—**it doesn’t even make sense to change the
>   value of a number**. It is not so obvious for strings, however.  Since strings are
>   like arrays of characters, you might expect to be able to alter the character at any
>   specified index.

Probably I'm just missing something due to my lack of CS background (self-taught and all...), but could anybody help me shed some light on it?

Particularly the part I've made emphasized:  Why it wouldn't make sense to change value of a number?

---

My ideas so far:

- maybe he's strictly distinguishing between concepts of (what in other language could be called)
  "variables" and "values".  Then OK, it really does not make sense to change value of 3 to value
  of 4 (so that `3 == 4`), but such explanation fails on the next sentence: such operation does
  not make any more sense for strings than for numbers...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right that it doesn't make sense to change the *value* of a string literal -- which is what he is in fact saying; he just says that it might not be as *obvious* as the `3 == 4` case, since you can reference individual characters in a string (and might then think you can change the string by changing a particular character).

Consider the example:

```
var s = 'hello world';
s[0] = 'H';
```

Intuitively this seems as if it would capitalize the word, but the string is *immutable* so that **won't work**.

Checking the output of `s` we still see: `s > 'hello world'`

Comment: Wow, 4 answers in 3 minutes... All basically said the same and all sent me in correct direction (all +1).  Your is the winner because of the magical `s[0] = 'H';` vhich reminded me of old Pascal (...was it Pascal?...) where you *could* do it.

Answer (score 2):

It's exactly how you intrepet it. It would not make sense to change the value of 3, such that `3 == 4`, for instance.

As far as strings are concerned, mutability of their values is seen in some languages like C, but not in others like Java. As such, it's not necessarily as readily apparent that they're immutable. There are arguments for and against either choice.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have a stronger grasp of the distinction than the author, or at least than the author gives you credit for. Your "ideas so far" is exactly right, but he thinks that many new users expect to be able to change string primitives, too. You don't, which means your expectations match up with how the language actually behaves, rather than with how he thinks you'll expect things.

Answer (score 1):

The string is immutable in JavaScript. He says it is "not so clear" for strings because it doesn't make much sense for many (perhaps it does for you though, clearly).  The best explanation I can offer is you define the string: "Bob".  You can rename the whole thing "Cob", but you cannot physically change the "B" to a "C" since internally that "B" was just a number (char representation). So you'd essentially be doing "B" = "C".  Or SomeNumber = AnotherNumber.